# How can I query for the entry or entries with the greatest array length in mongoose?

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

Each entry in my document contains a property `myProperty : [Number]`. I want to return the entry in which the `myProperty` array has the greatest length, or if there are multiple ones with the greatest length then return any one of them. How can I do this?

Say I have a model `const Model = require('./myModel');`

Answer (score 0):

**Simplest way**: record the length of `myProperty` in a separate field every time you update that list. For example, in a field called `myPropertyLength`.

Then you can just do a simple query like:

```
db.collection.find({}).sort({myPropertyLength: -1}).limit(1)
```

Create an index on the `myPropertyLength` field to make this operation faster.

**Complicated way**: use aggregation to add a field computing the array length:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$addFields: {myLength: {$size: '$myProperty'}}},
  {$sort: {myLength: -1}},
  {$limit: 1}
])
```

in the end, this method is just replicating the simpler method, only with a lot less efficiency. Also you can't use any index on this aggregation, so this can be a very expensive operation vs. the simple method.